# Posting to a page, can I access querystring values?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my asp.net-mvc application, I have a action method that I marked with the ActionVerb=POST.

When I do that, can I still access the querystring or only request.form values?

Answer (score 2):

You can still access the Query String since it will be send as part of the URL during a POST. That Attribute solely means that that Method can't be run in the absense of a POST.